# Hanging on localhost:9222 using the remote debugging feature in Chrome for Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, adb, chrome-for-android

I've followed the [official guide](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging) but when I enter in Chrome localhost:9222 it just hangs there "Waiting for localhost..." Nothing else.

I've enable USB debugging on my device and connected my device via USB

And when I run the command to enable the port I get the message as shown below:

[image]

I've tried to disable my firewall but that didn't fix it.

I've tried it in Firefox and I can see the Inspectable pages right away but then when I click on it I get "Remote debugging has been terminated with reason: websocket_closed"

Other usefull info to help you:

- I'm running on Chrome Version 26.0.1410.64 m
- Running on Nexus 4

Answer (score 1):

Use Chrome Canary instead, it has better, more integrated Mobile debugging support.

Plug in your Android device, run adb devices from the command line and then in Chrome Canary visit chrome://inspect. Your device should be listed there, and then you can debug the pages on the device with the DevTools that come with Chrome and not on the appspot domain.  You also no longer need to set up the local_abstract.

Comment: Also make sure you are in Dev mode on Andriod.